Do the bijections in the $(f^*, f_*)$ adjunction commute with restrictions to open sets?
$\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}$
Let $f : X \ra Y$ be a morphism of ringed spaces. Let $F$ be a sheaf of modules on $X$ and $G$ be a sheaf of modules on $Y$. Then, there is a bijection $\alpha_{FG} : Mor_{O_X-mod}(f^* G, F) \ra Mor_{O_Y-mod}(G, f_* F)$
Now, let $V \subseteq Y$ be an open set, and $U = f^{-1}(Y)$. Let $g : U \ra V$ be the restriction of $f$. Let $A$ be a sheaf of modules on $U$ and $B$ be a sheaf of modules on $V$.  We have a bijection $\beta_{AB} : Mor_{O_U-mod}(g^* B, A) \ra Mor_{O_V-mod}(B, g_*A)$.
Question : Suppose $A = F|_U, B = G|_V$. Let $t : f^* G \ra F$. Then, do we have $\beta_{AB}(t|_U) = \alpha_{FG}(t)|_V$?
My attempt at solving this is to use the construction of the bijection: Both $Mor_{O_X-mod}(f^* G, F)$ and $Mor_{O_Y-mod}(G, f_* F)$ are in bijection with $O_Y(U)$-module homomorphisms $G(U) \ra F(V) : U \subseteq Y, V \subseteq f^{-1}(U)$ that commute with restrictions. See exercise 2.7.B of Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry. I think a collection of module homomorphisms should "restrict" to a collection for $A$ and $B$, but I'm not sure how to define the restriction properly. We will have to "throw away" a lot of those module homomorphisms when doing the restriction, and I'm not sure if the bijection still holds after throwing them away.
If necessary, assume $X$ and $Y$ are schemes and all sheaves are quasicoherent.

Well, what else could happen? The bijections are defined naturally enough that no funny business can occur.
Since you appear to be having some issues with restriction, let's start with what it means to restrict a morphism of sheaves: if $F,G$ are two sheaves on $X$ with a morphism $\phi:F\to G$, this is a collection of compatible maps $\phi(U):F(U)\to G(U)$ for all open $U\subset X$. Then $\phi|_{X'}:F|_{X'}\to G|_{X'}$ for an open $X'\subset X$ is  given by the collection of compatible maps $\phi(U):F|_{X'}(U) = F(U)\to G(U) = G|_{X'}(U)$ for all open $U\subset X'$. So the map $\phi|_{X'}$ on an open set $U\subset X'$ is literally just the map from $\phi$ on that open set.
Now you can see that the answer to your question is yes: the maps from each of the hom-sets to this intermediate construction are defined by taking a map $\pi^{-1}G\to F$ or $G\to \pi_*F$ to a collection of maps $G(V)\to F(U)$ as $U$ runs over the opens of $X$ and $V\supset \pi(U)$, and by the fact that these come from morphisms of sheaves, they're compatible with restriction in the appropriate sense. Their restrictions are too, and in fact, if you trace the definition for where everything goes, you'll see that you end up in the same spot no matter what order you do things in.
Set $Y'\subset Y$ as an open set with preimage $X'\subset X$ and induced morphism $\pi':X'\to Y'$. In one direction, given a map $t:\pi^{-1}G\to F$ and an open subset $U\subset X'\subset X$, the component of the map $t(U)$ is sent to the collection $G(V)\to F(U)$ as $V$ ranges over opens of $Y$ containing $\pi(V)$. This is the same collection as is obtained when we consider where $t|_{X'}$ goes, since the opens $V\subset Y'$ containing $\pi'(U)=\pi(U)$ are cofinal in the diagram of opens $V\subset Y$ containing $\pi(U)$.
In the other direction, given a map $s:G\to \pi_*F$ and an open subset $V\subset Y'\subset Y$, we get a map $G(V)\to \pi_*F(V) = F(\pi^{-1}(V))$, which is the same thing we get when considering the restriction $s|_{Y'}(V)$.
Since both of the bijections from the hom-sets in to the auxiliary set $\operatorname{Hom}_{YX}(G,F)$ commute with restriction and the data of an element in this auxiliary hom-set tracks everything on every open subset of $X,Y$, everything matches up.
